# Can I call a function on accordion open only?

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

Im using Clarity v2 and I want to call a function on accordion open only and not on click.

Currently using something like this:

```
<clr-accordion>
    <clr-accordion-panel *ngFor="let tec of tecnic">
        <clr-accordion-title (click)="myFunction(tec)">{{tec.id}}</clr-accordion-title>
```

But **myFunction()** is getting called on open and close obviously.
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could tie into the de-sugared syntax of `clrAccordionPanelOpen`e.g:

```
<clr-accordion-panel *ngFor="let panel of panels" [clrAccordionPanelOpen]="panel.open" (clrAccordionPanelOpenChange)="panelChange($event, panel)">
```

Here is a simple working stackblitz I threw together to demonstrate this: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-58029735-accordion-open-function

Comment: (clrAccordionPanelOpenChange) did the trick. Didnt saw that on the documentation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a variable in your component to the [(clrIfExpanded)] directive of the Accordion.

So maybe something like:

```
<clr-accordion>
<clr-accordion-panel [(clrIfExpanded)]="isOpen" *ngFor="let tec of tecnic">
    <clr-accordion-title (click)="myFunction(tec)">{{tec.id}}</clr-accordion-title>
```

Then you could check the value of isOpen in myFunction()

See: https://clarity.design/documentation/accordion